# RS Web parts title doesn't change

Tags: web-part, reporting-services

After installing the RSwepart that come with SQL server 2008.
I noticed that the webpart title doesn't change. After i have tried changing it from Report Explorer to something else.

See them here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772(v=sql.105).aspx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has plagued me in 2007 and presumably is the same in 2010 from my initial tests.  I'll set the title to something and it'll revert to Report Viewer.  The only way around it is to hide the web part chrome so it doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Edit Web Part

**Step 2:** Click "View" Just above "Appearance" and "Parameters"

**Step 3:** Uncheck "Auto-Generate Web Part Title"

**Step 4:** Click "Apply"

**Step 5:** Click "Appearance"

**Step 6:** Change your title

**Step 7:** Click "Apply"

Done!

Comment: Hi Shaun, there is no Auto Generate webpart properties.
Can you confirm how you made this work?